# How can I show the table content only on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table as follows, I am trying something complex, I need to figure out how to display the "Hi", only on desktop devices. Or in other words, hide it from mobile devices.

I have a few onClick functions thrown in there that I want to keep. for both desktop and mobile devices.

Many thanks!

```
      <div class="col-sm-9 noPadding">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table  id="table2" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-xs-2">#</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Monday</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Tuesday</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Wednesday</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Thursday</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Friday</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="">09-10</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,0)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,0)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,0)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,0)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,0)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">10-11</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,1)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,1)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,1)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,1)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,1)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">11-12</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,2)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,2)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,2)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,2)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,2)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">12-01</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,3)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,3)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,3)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,3)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,3)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">01-02</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,4)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,4)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,4)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,4)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,4)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">02-03</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,5)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,5)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,5)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,5)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,5)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">03-04</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,6)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,6)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,6)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,6)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,6)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">04-05</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,7)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,7)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,7)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,7)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,7)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">05-06</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,8)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,8)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,8)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,8)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,8)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">06-07</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,9)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,9)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,9)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,9)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,9)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="">07-08</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(0,10)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(1,10)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(2,10)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(3,10)">Hi</td>
                <td class="" onclick="highlightUsers(4,10)">Hi</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div><!-- table-responsive" -->
      </div><!-- col-sm-9 -->
```

Comment: bootstrap has built in helper classes like "hidden-lg" use the one thats media querry only applies to anything less than desktop size. Here is a link to the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes. Don't use jquery to do what Bootstrap already lets you do with just CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: can you give us some feed back (comments or answers below). Can you also clarify if you want to hide text **only** ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Bootstrap, you can use the classes `hidden-xs` to hide elements in mobile devices. Example below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="">09-10</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs" onclick="highlightUsers(0,0)">Hi</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs" onclick="highlightUsers(1,0)">Hi</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs" onclick="highlightUsers(2,0)">Hi</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs" onclick="highlightUsers(3,0)">Hi</td>
    <td class="hidden-xs" onclick="highlightUsers(4,0)">Hi</td>
</tr>
```

But this will make your `onclick` event void since it won't be displayed.

If you want to keep the `onclick` event on the `td`s, set those `td`'s `visibility` as `hidden` for devices with width `<768px`. By that those elements will just be hidden without losing the area and the `onclick` listener.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following *[media query](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)* to target devices by screen size.  Playing with the `max-device-width` allows you control over which devices see what, and you can use the `onclick` attribute (or another attribute) to target the elements that you want to hide.

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1200px) { 
    td[onclick^="highlightUsers"] {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```